# Xbox Live Creators Program not allowed for apps

Tags: uwp, xbox, hosted-app, xbox-live

We are developing Xbox UWP hosted App with the use of Xbox Live SDK.
But submission page tells that:

> Xbox Live Creators Program only supports games. To submit this product, you must either remove it from Xbox Live Creators Program, or select Games for the category in the Properties page.

How to fix that besides category to game?
 The app needs to have access to XUID.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can only enable live services for titles that have been categorised as games on the store.  Any App that includes the Live Services API or attempts to acces Live API's will currently fail certification.

This is very sad and I've tried to get this changed but it seems that gamification of apps isn't on MS's radar at the moment.  Hopefully this will change in the future.

However, this wouldn't stop you from creating apps for sideloading pointing to a title listed as a game and consuming Live services.  You just can't publish it as an app, so it will only ever appear in the game category.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no other way to do that.  Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/create-and-test-a-new-creators-title#enable-xbox-live-services).

> Xbox Live is only supported for games. In order to successfully publish your game with Xbox Live, you must set your product type to "Game" in the properties section of the submission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does it somehow possible to get user's XUID as an app?

Comment: get user's XUID as an app? what is that mean?

Comment: Currently I am using Xbox Live SDK to get **Xbox User Id** with that code `Microsoft.Xbox.Services.System.XboxLiveUser().signInAsync(null)...`. That **Xbox User Id** I am using to get user's achievements list and registering user in the app. But with Xbox Live restrictions it's unable to get that Id as an application.
I am asking, does it possible to get **Xbox User Id** in another way?